# Block.Tile Positions () is unavailable due to its security level

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, class

I have TilePositions() component and when i tried change it from private to public i'm generic new error which is:
"Accessibility inconsistency, the return type "IEnumerable " is less accessible than the "Block.TilePositions ()" method
"

```
public abstract class Block
    {
        Position[][] Tiles { get; }  
        Position StartOffset { get; }    
        public abstract int Id { get; }

        private int rotationState;
        private Position offset;


        public Block()
        {
            offset = new Position(StartOffset.Row, StartOffset.Column);
        }


        private IEnumerable<Position> TilePositions() //here is error
        {
            foreach (Position p in Tiles[rotationState])
            {
                yield return new Position(p.Row + offset.Row, p.Column + offset.Column);
             
            }
        }
}
```

```
private bool BlockFits()
        {
            foreach (Position p in CurrentBlock.TilePositions())
            {
                if (!GameGrid.IsEmpty(p.Row,p.Column))
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: How is the `Position` class defined? Is it `public`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change private to public for access from out object.

```
 public IEnumerable<Position> TilePositions() //here is error
    {
        foreach (Position p in Tiles[rotationState])
        {
            yield return new Position(p.Row + offset.Row, p.Column + offset.Column);
         
        }
    }
```

**public :**  In c#, the public modifier is used to specify that access is not restricted, so the defined type or member can be accessed by any other code in the current assembly or another assembly that references it.

**private** : In c#, the private modifier is used to specify that access is limited to the containing type, so the defined type or member can only be accessed by the code in the same class or structure.

Comment: I already do it before i wrote this on question.And now i have error:"Accessibility inconsistency, the return type "IEnumerable " is less accessible than the "Block.TilePositions ()" method" @thisisnabi

Comment: Accessibility inconsistency! Position class is on accessible namespace?? modifier for Position must be public when you use it on public method.